# How to resolve required option id missing error when I send SNMP data using snmp-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, snmp

I am writing the sample code below using `Nodejs`. When I run the code throws a `new Error('Missing required option oid.');` I am getting the error. What I want to do is `next`, `walk`, `getNext` etc with the `Mib` browser. I want these values ​​to come when transactions are made.

```
const snmp = require('snmp-native');

  const options = {
       host: '192.168.2.80',
       community: 'public',
       port: 161,
       version: snmp.Version2c 
  };


  const session = new snmp.Session(options);

  const oidsAndValues = [
      { oid: '1.3.4.6.7', value: 23 },
      { oid: '1.3.4.6.8', value: 25 }
  ];


 oidsAndValues.forEach(item => {
    session.set([{
        oid: item.oid,
        type: snmp.DataTypes.Integer,
       value: item.value
    }], (error, varbinds) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log('SetAsync varbinds:', varbinds);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Orifjon The `option` of `Session()` doesn't require the `oid`.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the documentation, https://github.com/calmh/node-snmp-native

The `session.set()` method accepts an `Object` **BUT** you passed an `Array`. The code should be,

```js
// Add leading .
const oidsAndValues = [
      { oid: '.1.3.4.6.7', value: 23 },
      { oid: '.1.3.4.6.8', value: 25 }
  ];

oidsAndValues.forEach(item => {
    session.set({
        oid: item.oid,
        type: snmp.DataTypes.Integer,
       value: item.value
    }, (error, varbinds) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log('SetAsync varbinds:', varbinds);
        }
    });
});
```

**Alternative Approach**

```
const oidsAndValues = [
      { oid: '.1.3.4.6.7', type: snmp.DataTypes.Integer, value: 23 },
      { oid: '.1.3.4.6.8', type: snmp.DataTypes.Integer, value: 25 }
  ];

oidsAndValues.forEach(item => {
    session.set( item, (error, varbinds) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        } else {
            console.log('SetAsync varbinds:', varbinds);
        }
    });
});
```